# Rascal: Grammar Stack Trace

Tags: debugging, grammar, rascal

When parsing a file with a specific grammar and the parse fails, I get a corresponding error message with the location in the source file that offended the grammar.

What I would like to look at in these situations would be the list of grammar rules that were active at this moment, something like a grammar rule "stack trace", or the rules that have matched so far.
Is this possible in Rascal?

So, for a very simple example, in the EXP language from the documentation, if I tried to parse "2 + foo" I could get something like

```
Exp
=> left Exp "+" Exp
=> left IntegerLiteral "+" Exp
=> left IntegerLiteral "+" <?>
No derivation of "foo" from rule 'Exp'
```

Another way of saying this is looking at an incomplete parse tree, as it was the moment the parse error occurred. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes total sense, but I'm afraid this "incomplete parse tree" feature is on our TODO list.

Note that with the non-deterministic parsing algorithm it would probably return a set of current parse contexts, so a "parse forest" rather than a single stack trace. Still I think that would be a very useful debugging feature.

The only suggestion right now I can do right now is "delta-debugging", so removing half the input and checking if the parse error is still there, then the other half, rinse/lather/repeat.

Comment: Check! - BTW, the parse error I had seemed to be due to the repl getting confused with all the imported grammars. I'll make that the topic of my next question .

Comment: Excellent! That is a known problem actually; the state of modules in the repl